# How do I check if a letter is in a word?

Tags: python

How do I check if a letter is in a word? I want to check if `A` is in `ABC`? How do I do that?

My code so far:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower() 
    first = word[0]
    if 'a, e, i, o, u' in original: # ?
     print vowel
      else: 
      print consonant 
else:
    print 'empty'
```

Comment: This checks to see if `'a, e, i, o, u'` is in the original. You'd need to check each one on it's own.

Comment: Please don't just dump the 'quality standards' text into your question to make it pass the tests. Instead, **fix your post**.

Answer (score 4):

One way to check whether the word contains any vowels is:

```
if any(vowel in original for vowel in 'aeiou'):
```

Another way is:

```
if set('aeiou').intersection(original):
```

(You might want to factor the `set('aeiou')` out of the `if`.)

If you just want to check whether the given letter is a vowel, you could use:

```
if letter in 'aeiou':
```

Comment: `set('aeiou').intersection(original)` would be better

Comment: @JonClements: Isn't that just a slightly different way to spell my second suggestion? (Not sure if you were looking at an older edit, or there's some genuine difference I'm overlooking.)

Comment: It doesn't require `original` to be a set... so it removes an unnecessary operation

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the code you posted has anything to do with what you asked, but to answer your question:

> > > How do I check if a letter is in a word? I want to check if A is in ABC? How do I do that?

It's this simple:

```
>>> 'A' in 'ABC'
True
```